# Deleting an object in NSArrayController

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, nsarraycontroller

I have an `NSTableView` which gets its data from an `NSArrayController` and I need to delete the currently selected row.  I know `NSManagedObjectContext` has a `deleteObject:` method but, I can't think of how to delete it from the `NSArrayController`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `NSArrayController`'s [`remove:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSArrayController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002042-BBCDEDBC) action.

Answer (score 1):

To remove programmatically

```
[NSArrayController removeObjectAtArrangedObjectIndex:NSInteger];
```

or

```
[NSArrayController removeObjectAtArrangedObjectIndexes:NSIndexset];
```

Answer (score 0):

@NewStack's answer in Swift 3:

```
ArrayController.remove(atArrangedObjectIndex: Int)
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers from dreamlax, NewStack, styl3r are correct. But if you want to do this in code, here's the answer:

```
@IBOutlet var notesResultsController: NSArrayController!
@IBAction func deleteSelectedNote(_ sender: Any) {

    let selectedRow = tableView.selectedRow
    notesResultsController.remove(atArrangedObjectIndex: selectedRow)
}
```

Drag the NSArrayController onto your ViewController and hook up its outlet.
Add a button to your interface and hook up its action to 'deleteSelectedNote'.